# jquery + php load more

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm facing problem with jquery

here is my code

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery-1.10.2.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$(".more2").click(function() {
   var element = $(this);
   var msg = element.attr("id");

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
        url: "insta2.php",
        data: "lastmsg="+ encodeURIComponent(msg),  

            success:function (data) {

                $("#morebutton").replaceWith(data);

            }   
});



    return false;
    });
});
</script>



  <span class="more" id="morebutton">
  <a id="1" class="more2" title="Follow" href="#" style="color:#000">
               Read More
</a>
 </span>
```

and here is insta2.php

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['lastmsg']))
{
$a=  $_POST['lastmsg'];
$a = $a++;
?>
<br>
  <span class="more" id="morebutton">
  <a id="<?php echo $a;?>" class="more2" title="Follow" href="#" style="color:#000">
    <?php echo $a;?>           Read More
</a> </span>
<?php }?>
```

my jquery only one 1 set and after that every click not working

is there any way to continue counting ?

like this

Read More 
1 Read More 
2 Read More 
3 Read More 
4 Read More 
and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Your ajaxed in content does not have the jquery listener attached to it. Basically, your jquery will run only on your original HTML.

You can bind your click event to an element that is always on the page using the [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function, and use the selector parameter to define your read more links. (Please read the jQuery manual for more info on this).

Eg:

```
$('body').on('click', 'span.more', function(){
     // Do your ajax stuff
});
```

This will bind the click event to your body as opposed to 'span.more' and will work for any span.more added to the body.

Edit - JS Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/g8G83/

Comment: Check my answer for the JS fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

```
<span id="more">
    <a id="1" class="more2" title="Follow" href="#" style="color:#000">
        Read More
    </a>
</span>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $(".more2").click(function readmore() {
            var element = $(this);
            var msg = element.attr("id");
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
                url: "insta2.php",
                data: "lastmsg="+ encodeURIComponent(msg),  

                    success:function (data) {
                        $("#more").append(data);
                        $(".more2").off("click");
                        $(".more2").on("click",readmore);
                    }   
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```